# How to transfer dai for eth with syncswap api with ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, zksync

Hi，I had referred to [this article](https://syncswap.gitbook.io/api-documentation/guides/request-swap-with-router/swap-eth-for-dai) and now I want to test  swap dai to eth with syncswap api.

But I also get the insufficient funds error, actually, there's enough eth and dai in the wallet.

```js
//balances

0.14671552290491718 ETH
274859749945138530 DAI
```

```js
//erros

ERRORS: Error: insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS ] (error={"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"error\":{\"code\":3,\"message\":\"Failed to submit transaction: insufficient funds for gas + value. balance: 146715522904917175, fee: 3500000000000000000, value: 172989943652341920000000000000000000\",\"data\":{\"code\":104,\"message\":\"insufficient funds for gas + value. balance: 146715522904917175, fee: 3500000000000000000, value: 172989943652341920000000000000000000\"}},\"id\":56}\n","error":{"code":3,"data":{"code":104,"message":"insufficient funds for gas + value. balance: 146715522904917175, fee: 3500000000000000000, value: 172989943652341920000000000000000000"}},"requestBody":"{\"method\":\"eth_sendRawTransaction\"....
```

- `value` means the dai amount I want to transfer.
- Swap Dai For Eth codes

```js
// JavaScript

public static async swapDaiToEth(daiAddress: string, wETHAddress: string) {
  // The factory of the Classic Pool.
  const classicPoolFactory: Contract = new Contract(
      this.classicPoolFactoryAddress,
      this.classicPoolFactoryAbi,
      this.provider
  );

  // Gets the address of the ETH/DAI Classic Pool.
  // wETH is used internally by the pools.
  const poolAddress: string = await classicPoolFactory.getPool(daiAddress, wETHAddress);

  // Checks whether the pool exists.
  if (poolAddress === ZERO_ADDRESS) {
      throw Error('Pool not exists');
  }

  // Gets the reserves of the pool.
  const pool: Contract = new Contract(poolAddress, this.poolAbi, this.provider);
  const reserves: [BigNumber, BigNumber] = await pool.getReserves(); // Returns tuple (uint, uint)

  // Sorts the reserves by token addresses.
  const [reserveETH, reserveDAI] = wETHAddress < daiAddress ? reserves : [reserves[1], reserves[0]];

  // The input amount of ETH
  const value = 100000000;

  // Constructs the swap paths with steps.
  // Determine withdraw mode, to withdraw native ETH or wETH on last step.
  // 0 - vault internal transfer
  // 1 - withdraw and unwrap to naitve ETH
  // 2 - withdraw and wrap to wETH
  const withdrawMode = 1; // 1 or 2 to withdraw to user's wallet

  const swapData: string = defaultAbiCoder.encode(
      ["address", "address", "uint8"],
      [daiAddress, this.signer.address, withdrawMode], // tokenIn, to, withdraw mode
  );

  // We have only 1 step.
  const steps = [{
      pool: poolAddress,
      data: swapData,
      callback: ZERO_ADDRESS, // we don't have a callback
      callbackData: '0x',
  }];

  // If we want to use the native ETH as the input token,
  // the `tokenIn` on path should be replaced with the zero address.
  // Note: however we still have to encode the wETH address to pool's swap data.
  const nativeETHAddress = ZERO_ADDRESS;

  // We have only 1 path.
  const paths = [{
      steps: steps,
      tokenIn: daiAddress,
      amountIn: value,
  }];

  // Gets the router contract.
  const router: Contract = new Contract(this.routerAddress, this.routerAbi, this.provider);

  // Note: checks approval for ERC20 tokens.
  // The router will handle the deposit to the pool's vault account.
  const response = await router.swap(
      paths, // paths
      0, // amountOutMin // Note: ensures slippage here
      BigNumber.from(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)).add(1800), // deadline // 30 minutes
      {
          value: value,
      }
  );

  await response.wait();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I share with you the working code. I can swap between ETH and DAI on SyncSwap Era Testnet.

I tried this on ETH/USDC, but it's not working for large amount of USDC, only small amount. I think that maybe the pool is not enough liquidity and we had to split the token in amount and find routes to swap.

```
async function syncSwapETHUSDC(account: WalletAccount, amountStr: string, direction: number = 0) {
    const wETHAddress = Constants.getSyncSwapWETHArrd()
    const usdcAddress = Constants.getUSDCAddress()
    const routerAddress = Constants.getSyncSwapRouterAddress()
    const classicPoolFactoryAddress = Constants.getSyncSwapClassicPoolFactoryAddress()
    const classicPoolFactoryAbi = require("../abi/SyncSwapClassicPoolFactoryABI.json")
    const routerAbi = require("../abi/SyncSwapRouterABI.json");

    const signer = new zksync.Wallet("privateKey", zkSyncProvider, ethProvider)

    var tokenInAddress = ""
    var amount: ethers.BigNumber

    if (direction == 0) {
        tokenInAddress = wETHAddress
        amount = ethers.utils.parseEther(amountStr)
    } else {
        tokenInAddress = usdcAddress
        amount = ethers.utils.parseUnits(amountStr, 6)
        console.log(ethers.utils.formatUnits(amount, 6))
        
        const usdcContract = new ethers.Contract(usdcAddress, zksync.utils.IERC20, signer)
        console.log("----")
        let allowedAmount: ethers.BigNumber = await usdcContract.allowance(signer.address, routerAddress)
        console.log(ethers.utils.formatUnits(allowedAmount, 6))

        if (allowedAmount.lte(amount)) {
            
            let approveTx = await usdcContract.approve(routerAddress, amount)
            await approveTx.wait()
        } 
    }
    console.log(tokenInAddress)
    // The factory of the Classic Pool.
    const classicPoolFactory = new zksync.Contract(
        classicPoolFactoryAddress,
        classicPoolFactoryAbi,
        zkSyncProvider
    );

    // Gets the address of the ETH/USDC Classic Pool.
    // wETH is used internally by the pools.
    const poolAddress = await classicPoolFactory.getPool(wETHAddress, usdcAddress);

    // Checks whether the pool exists.
    if (poolAddress === ethers.constants.AddressZero) {
        console.log('pool not exists')
        return
    }

   
    const withdrawMode = 1; // 1 or 2 to withdraw to user's wallet

    const swapData: string = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
        ["address", "address", "uint8"],
        [tokenInAddress, signer.address, withdrawMode], // tokenIn, to, withdraw mode
    );

    const steps = [{
        pool: poolAddress,
        data: swapData,
        callback: ethers.constants.AddressZero,
        callbackData: '0x',
    }];


    const paths = [{
        steps: steps,
        tokenIn: (direction == 0) ? ethers.constants.AddressZero : tokenInAddress,
        amountIn: amount,
    }];
    console.log(paths)

    const router = new zksync.Contract(routerAddress, routerAbi, signer);

    const response = await router.swap(
        paths, // paths
        0, // amountOutMin // Note: ensures slippage here
        ethers.BigNumber.from(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)).add(1800), // deadline // 30 minutes
        {
            //value: amount, // please uncomment this if your token in is ETH
            gasLimit: 14000000
        }
    );

    let tx = await response.wait();
    console.log(tx.transactionHash)
}
```

Comment: It's great, thanks so much. If you have some spare time, could you teach me how to add and remove pools? I had read this [article](https://syncswap.gitbook.io/api-documentation/core-architecture/router), but without examples,I don't know how to use these functions correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This error message you received indicates that there is not enough `ETH` in your account to cover the **transaction fees**.

You need to either **add more ETH** to your account or reduce the `value` being transferred in the transaction.

Comment: I don't think so. I think eth 0.146 is enough for gas.  And I swap dai for eth in Website page, the gas is not as high. Maybe some wrong with the swap codes.